# python parallel with shared numpy array

Tags: python, joblib

I'm writing an iterative algorithm, where the most time consuming part is the execution of a function `oneiter()` which looks like the following:

```
def oneiter(M,h):
    res = []
    for i in range(M.shape[2]):
        res.append(f(M[:,:,i],h))
    return res
```

where `M` is a large n by n by p numpy array, and `f` is a function that does some kind of regression using `M[:,:,i]` and `h`. In all the iterations, `M` stays the same and `h` can be different.

To make it faster, I tried to parallelize the `for` loop in `oneiter` using joblib:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(f)(M[:,:,i],h) for i in range(M.shape[2]))
```

This way turned out to be even slower. I am very new to writing parallelized python code. Could somebody tell why this happened, and what are some better ways to do it?